# Slice string till next char

Tags: python, list

Assume I have this kind of string `Y18C9A8B88` and i want to get something like this

```
Y18C9A8B88.cut()
>>> [Y,18],[C,9],[A,8],[B,88]
```

I succeed doing that if the length of the num is equals to one but if its bigger it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression for this:

```
import re
re.findall("(\w+?)(\d+)", "Y18C9A8B88")
```

Breakdown:

- `"\w+?"` captures all strings up to the next digit and "\d+" capture all the digits (the `?` ensure it does not capture letters that could be dealt with `"\d"`).
- The parenthesis tell it which part belong to which group.
- `re.findall` makes sure that we try to match until the string is exhausted.

Comment: but what if i want to add them into a list and not a tupple

Comment: You can convert it to list of lists easily with `list(map(list, re.findall("(\w+?)(\d+)", "Y18C9A8B88")))`.

Comment: amazing ! can you explain what map does?

Comment: `map` runs the same functions over all element of an iterable. It returns a special object, which I converted to list. It is part of the functional programming side of python (see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#built-in-functions)

Comment: A problem with that map approach is that numbers are still strings and not integers.

Comment: In that case you can run `results = [ [result[0], int(result[1])] for result in results ]`, in similar way to your answer (note that it is `[1]` here and not `[1:]`). However, it is not clear from the question if that was required.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the letters are capital and 1 letter is followed by n numbers then

```py
import re
results = re.findall('[A-Z][0-9]*', "Y18C9A8B88")
results = [ [result[0], int(result[1:])] for result in results ]
```

Results is equal to:

```py
[['Y', 18], ['C', 9], ['A', 8], ['B', 88]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in the remote case scenario that you don't want to use regular expressions, you can try:

```py
string = 'Y18C9A8B88'
letters = [ch for ch in string if ch.isalpha()]
nums = "".join([ch if ch.isdigit() else ' ' for ch in string]).strip().split()
result = [[*tuple_] for tuple_ in zip(letters, nums)]
```

**Output:**

```
[['Y', '18'], ['C', '9'], ['A', '8'], ['B', '88']]
```